# How to add dictionary values to images using SpriteKit?

Tags: swift3, sprite-kit

(( EDIT 4:  Successful in making cards flip.  Using .contains on the node and running a SKAction sequence.  How would I create three states for the card?  Tuple sounds like a fun idea.  Unflipped, Flipped, Flipped-Highlighted.  It loads with all cards down (done), I want to unflip the card (done), then tap it again to highlight it.  In doing so the second time, it highlights itself and the top guess word.  The two strings are then concatenated in a label at the bottom, and a Next button activated (not built yet).  Upon successful match of the key[value] == A[B] then Score += 1.  Getting closer! ))

(( EDIT 3: Update of didMove with split keys and values. Can get the title to be the first key now and I can put the first value on the top left card okay as a test. Progress. Now I just need to either blank out the card on touch down or find a way to flip it. How would the touch down code be done? touch Began? ))

(( EDIT 2: Now thinking of it from the perspective of dictionary key value pairs rather than values alone.  Gets rid of the problem of finding the key when the value is assigned to the card.  Now to play with labelling the card with SKLabelNode.  Need to flip card, add value, compare key.  ))

(( EDIT: I made the elements all code in GameScene.swift .  That file is now included in this post.  Also updated question text and removed some other text. ))

I'm new to SpriteKit and Swift 3.  With a few million speakers there's not a lot of Esperanto software so I want to make a game for myself to learn 1000 Esperanto words.  (not shown!)

[image]

I want to have each card flip to reveal a word **value** from the dictionary key/values.

Then see if that word matches the wordGuess label **key** for the value selected.

Also JSON might be better for breaking up 1000 words into modular sections but I'll cross that bridge at another time.

```
// Code updated to EDIT 4
//  
//

import SpriteKit


class GameScene: SKScene {

    let guessLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "HelveticaNeue-UltraLight")
    let anotherLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "HelveticaNeue-UltraLight")

    var cardTopLeftLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Arial-BoldMT")
    let cardTopLeft = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Redcard")

    var cardTopRightLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Arial-BoldMT")
    let cardTopRight = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Redcard")

    var cardBottomLeftLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Arial-BoldMT")
    let cardBottomLeft = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Redcard")

    var cardBottomRightLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Arial-BoldMT")
    let cardBottomRight = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Redcard")

    var cardsDictionary: [String:String] = [
        "tree": "arbo",
        "forest": "arbaro",
        "spider": "araneo",
        "water": "akvo",
        "watermelon": "akvomelono",
        "school": "lerno",
        "year": "jaro",
        "grasshopper": "akrido",
        "lawn": "gazono",
        "friend": "amiko",
        "people": "homoj",
        "city": "urbo",
        "mayor": "urbestro",
        "movie": "filmo",
        "Monday": "lundo",
        "dog": "hundo"
    ]





    // not used yet
    func randomSequenceGenerator(min: Int, max: Int) -> () -> Int {
        var numbers: [Int] = []
        return {
            if numbers.count == 0 {
                numbers = Array(min ... max)
            }

            let index = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(numbers.count)))
            return numbers.remove(at: index)
        }
    }



    func addLabel(spriteNode:SKSpriteNode, labelNode: SKLabelNode, cardValue: String, cardName: String) {
        labelNode.zPosition = 1
        labelNode.text = cardValue
        labelNode.name = cardName //"cardTopRightLabel"
        labelNode.fontSize = 40
        labelNode.fontColor = .black
        labelNode.position = CGPoint.init(x: cardTopLeft.size.width/4, y: 0.5)
        labelNode.isHidden = true
        spriteNode.addChild(labelNode)
    }


    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

        if let words = self.userData?.value(forKey: "words")
        {
            print("word information contains \(words)")
        }

        // get all the card keys
        var cardKeys:[String] = []
        for (k,_) in cardsDictionary {
            cardKeys.append(k)
        }
        print("all keys are \(cardKeys)")

        // slice for four card keys
        var fourCardKeys = cardKeys[0...3]
        print("four keys are \(fourCardKeys)")

        // get keys for display
        var firstCardKey = fourCardKeys[0]
        var secondCardKey = fourCardKeys[1]
        var thirdCardKey = fourCardKeys[2]
        var fourthCardKey = fourCardKeys[3]
//        print("Card Keys are \(firstCardKey), \(secondCardKey), \(thirdCardKey), \(fourthCardKey)")

        // get the card values
        var cardsValue:[String] = []
        for (_,v) in cardsDictionary {
            cardsValue.append(v)
        }
        print(cardsValue)

        // slice for card values
        let fourCardValues = cardsValue[0...3]
        print(fourCardValues)

        // get values for display
        let firstCardValue  = fourCardValues[0]
        let secondCardValue = fourCardValues[1]
        let thirdCardValue = fourCardValues[2]
        let fourthCardValue = fourCardValues[3]
        print("Card Values are  \(firstCardValue), \(secondCardValue), \(thirdCardValue), \(fourthCardValue)")


        // put first card key into label
        guessLabel.zPosition = 1
        guessLabel.text = firstCardKey //cardKeys[0]
        guessLabel.name = "guessLabel"
        guessLabel.fontSize = 144;
        guessLabel.fontColor = .black
        //anotherLabel.position = CGPoint(x:frame.midX, y:frame.midY - 100.0)
        guessLabel.position = CGPoint(x:-2, y:233)
        addChild(guessLabel)


        anotherLabel.zPosition = 0
        anotherLabel.text = "Guess key here, values in cards"
        anotherLabel.name = "anotherLabel"
        anotherLabel.fontSize = 45;
        anotherLabel.fontColor = .blue
        //anotherLabel.position = CGPoint(x:frame.midX, y:frame.midY - 100.0)
        anotherLabel.position = CGPoint(x:-2, y:203)
        addChild(anotherLabel)


        ////////////////
        // top left card
        cardTopLeft.zPosition = 0
        cardTopLeft.size = CGSize(width: 300.0, height: 300.0)
        cardTopLeft.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
        cardTopLeft.position = CGPoint(x:-229, y:-57)
        addChild(cardTopLeft)

        addLabel(spriteNode: cardTopLeft,
                 labelNode: cardTopLeftLabel,
                 cardValue: firstCardValue,
                 cardName: "cardTopLeftLabel")


        /////////////////
        // top right card
        cardTopRight.zPosition = 1
        cardTopRight.size = CGSize(width: 300.0, height: 300.0)
        cardTopRight.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
        cardTopRight.position = CGPoint(x:132, y:-57)
        addChild(cardTopRight)

        addLabel(spriteNode: cardTopRight,
                 labelNode: cardTopRightLabel,
                 cardValue: secondCardValue,
                 cardName: "cardTopRightLabel")

        ///////////////////
        // bottom left card
        cardBottomLeft.zPosition = 1
        cardBottomLeft.size = CGSize(width: 300.0, height: 300.0)
        cardBottomLeft.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
        cardBottomLeft.position = CGPoint(x:-225, y:-365)
        addChild(cardBottomLeft)

        addLabel(spriteNode: cardBottomLeft,
                 labelNode: cardBottomLeftLabel,
                 cardValue: thirdCardValue,
                 cardName: "cardBottomLeftLabel")

        ////////////////////
        // bottom right card
        cardBottomRight.zPosition = 1
        cardBottomRight.size = CGSize(width: 300.0, height: 300.0)
        cardBottomRight.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
        cardBottomRight.position = CGPoint(x:132, y:-365)
        addChild(cardBottomRight)

        addLabel(spriteNode: cardBottomRight,
                 labelNode: cardBottomRightLabel,
                 cardValue: fourthCardValue,
                 cardName: "cardBottomRightLabel")

    }


    func touchDown(atPoint pos : CGPoint)
    {

    }

    func touchMoved(toPoint pos : CGPoint) {

    }

    func touchUp(atPoint pos : CGPoint) {


    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {


        guard let touch = touches.first else {
            return
        }

        let touchLocation = touch.location(in: self)
        let touchedNode = self.atPoint(touchLocation)


        func flipCard (node: SKNode, label: SKLabelNode)
        {
            label.isHidden = true

            node.run(SKAction.sequence(
                [SKAction.scaleX(to: 0, duration: 0.2),
                 SKAction.scale(to: 1, duration: 0.0),
                 SKAction.setTexture(SKTexture(imageNamed: "Redcard-blank"))
                                 ]
            ))
            label.isHidden = false
        }

        func flipCardPause (node: SKNode, interval: Double)
        {
            node.run(SKAction.wait(forDuration: interval))
            print("paused for \(interval) seconds")
        }

        func flipCardBack (node: SKNode, label: SKLabelNode)
        {
            label.isHidden = true

            node.run(SKAction.sequence(
                [SKAction.scaleX(to: 1, duration: 0.2),
                 SKAction.setTexture(SKTexture(imageNamed: "Redcard"))
                 // SKAction.scale(to: 1, duration: 0.2)


                ]
            ))
        }


        if cardTopLeft.contains(touchLocation)
        {
            flipCard(node: cardTopLeft, label: cardTopLeftLabel)
            //flipCardPause(node: cardTopLeft, interval: 3)
            //flipCardBack(node: cardTopLeft, label: cardTopLeftLabel)
        }

        if cardTopRight.contains(touchLocation)
        {
            flipCard(node: cardTopRight, label: cardTopRightLabel)

        }

        if cardBottomLeft.contains(touchLocation)
        {
            flipCard(node: cardBottomLeft, label: cardBottomLeftLabel)
        }

        if cardBottomRight.contains(touchLocation)
        {
            flipCard(node: cardBottomRight, label: cardBottomRightLabel)
        }

        for t in touches { self.touchDown(atPoint: t.location(in: self)) }

    }
```

<strike>How to assign dictionary values to the cards?</strike>. EDIT 2: By not using values!  I'm going to do from the perspective of dictionary keys, that way each card has a key value pair, then just display the value.

```
// get all the card keys
var cardKeys:[String] = []
for (k,_) in cardsDictionary {
    cardKeys.append(k)
}

// slice for only four cards
var fourCardKeys = cardKeys[0...3]

// get 1st value for display
cardsDictionary[fourCardKeys[0]]
```

So SKLabelNode on touchDown?  I'll try it.  Also need to flip card so word is not on the image.  Lastly compare the pressed card's key to the wordGuess key text.  Getting closer

EDIT 3: Update of didMove with split keys and values.  Can get the title to be the first key now and I can put the first value on the top left card okay as a test.  Progress.  Now I just need to either blank out the card on touchDown or find a way to flip it.

```
    cardTopLeft.zPosition = 0
    cardTopLeft.size = CGSize(width: 300.0, height: 300.0)
    cardTopLeft.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
    cardTopLeft.position = CGPoint(x:-229, y:-57)
    addChild(cardTopLeft)

    cardTopLeftLabel.zPosition = 1
    cardTopLeftLabel.text = fourCardValues[0]
    cardTopLeftLabel.name = "cardTopLeftLabel"
    cardTopLeftLabel.fontSize = 40
    cardTopLeftLabel.fontColor = .black
    cardTopLeftLabel.position = CGPoint.init(x: cardTopLeft.size.width/4, y: 0.5)
    cardTopLeft.addChild(cardTopLeftLabel)
```

[image]

EDIT 4:  Successful in making cards flip.  Using .contains on the node and running a SKAction sequence.  How would I create three states for the card?  Tuple sounds like a fun idea.  Unflipped, Flipped, Flipped-Highlighted.  It loads with all cards down (done), I want to unflip the card (done), then tap it again to highlight it (help?).  In doing so the second time, it highlights itself and the top guess word.  The two strings are then concatenated in a label at the bottom, and a Next button activated (not built yet).  Upon successful match of the key[value] == A[B] then Score += 1.  Getting closer!  It's really similar to just a matching game but I'm adding an extra layer of card flipping.

```
 override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {       

        guard let touch = touches.first else {
            return
        }

        let touchLocation = touch.location(in: self)
        let touchedNode = self.atPoint(touchLocation)


        func flipCard (node: SKNode, label: SKLabelNode)
        {
            label.isHidden = true

            node.run(SKAction.sequence(
                [SKAction.scaleX(to: 0, duration: 0.2),
                 SKAction.scale(to: 1, duration: 0.0),
                 SKAction.setTexture(SKTexture(imageNamed: "Redcard-blank"))
                                 ]
            ))
            label.isHidden = false
        }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I don't like to use userData, my opinion is that isn't a readable code.

I'd some like to create a custom SKNode like:

```
class Card: SKSpriteNode {
    var value....
    var dictionary
    etc
}
```

Another solution, you can create a tuples:

```
var cardsDictionary: [String:String] = [
        "vegetable":"legomo",
        "plant":"vegetalo",
        "actually":"efektive",
        "currently":"aktuale"
    ]
let cardTopLeft = (node:SKNode, value:Int, type:[String:String])

cardTopLeft.node = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Redcard")
cardTopLeft.value = 1
cardTopLeft.type = cardsDictionary[0]
```

Comment: I think I'm going to edit the question as a JSON file using SwiftyJSON so I can get an .arrayValue . Tuple might be useful to keep track of order like an Array pair as well.

Comment: Sorry this doesn't work for me as additional properties of cardTopLeft are used to set position, image, etc

Comment: ???? once you have the node you can modify his propriety. cardTopLeft.node.position = .....

Comment: Thanks I didn't know that. I'll give it a look again.  I'm new to all this

Answer (score 1):

All SKNodes have a dictionary you can write to called `userData`.  It is an optional NSMutableDictionary, so you are going to have to create it:

```
    cardTopLeft.zPosition = 1
    cardTopLeft.size = CGSize(width: 300.0, height: 300.0)
    cardTopLeft.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
    cardTopLeft.position = CGPoint(x:-229, y:-57)
    cardTopLeft.userData = ["word":"tree","value","arbo"]
    addChild(cardTopLeft)
```

To use:

```
    let word = cardTopLeft.userData["word"]
    let value = cardTopLeft.userData["value"]
```

Getting a better understanding of your question, I would use `SKLabelNode` as an alternative.

What you can do is create `SKLabelNode`s to the cards with the word you want to attach, and mark it as `isHidden = true`.  When you are ready to reveal the word, you just mark `isHidden = false`

```
    let value = SKLabelNode("arbo")
    value.isHidden = false      

    cardTopLeft.zPosition = 1
    cardTopLeft.size = CGSize(width: 300.0, height: 300.0)
    cardTopLeft.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
    cardTopLeft.position = CGPoint(x:-229, y:-57)
    cardTopLeft.addChild(value)
    addChild(cardTopLeft)


    //to reveal it
    if let label = cardTopLeft.children[0] as? SKLabelNode
    { 
        label.isHidden = false
    }

    //to use it
    if let label = cardTopLeft.children[0] as? SKLabelNode
    { 
        let value = label.text
        //compare value to dictionary of answers
    }
```

You may want to give your labels a name so that you do not have to use children[0], but I will leave how you want to find a node up to you.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.  That's interesting, I'll play around with it to see how that works dynamically to the Node for each set of 4 cards.

Comment: Your post was helpful in me realizing I needed to put both the key and value pair with each card, then just display the value.  That way I don't require more data structures like userData.  I'm going to try working with SKLabelNode too.  Thanks for your post, it has helped me realize what direction to take.

Comment: You want to keep your data modularized and contained.  By doing just a key value pair that is not attached to the node, you run risks of that data being broken and no longer existing, which could crash your app.  This is kind of like having an ID. Sure you can give it to your mom to hold, but what happens when your mom loses or destroys it.  Or what happens when somebody else needs to see your ID, are you going to call your mom and tell her to bring it to you?  It is better for you to carry your ID on you.

Comment: That's why we have key chains.  So the cardKeys will hold the keys for me.  I can then derive the value based on the slice index and use that for the Node label.  I'll try it after dinner ;)

Comment: what do you mean?